# Calculus of Variations: Having trouble finding y(x)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, indefinite-integrals, calculus-of-variations

I've worked my way through a variations problem and I've arrived to two integrals:

$$\int dx = \int {1\over \sqrt[]{{y^2\over c^2}-1}}dy $$

Solving for them, I find

$$x+c_2 = c_1\ln (c_1\sqrt[]{{y^2\over c_1^2}-1}+y)$$

And here I'm stuck. I'm looking for $y(x)$, but it doesn't seem clear to me how to approach this. I've looked at

$$e^{x+c_2\over c_1} =c_1 \sqrt[]{{y^2\over c_1^2}-1}+y$$

But that doesn't seem to get me anywhere. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

You have $$\left(\frac{e^{\frac{x+c_2}{c_1}}-y}{c_1}\right)^2=\frac{y^2}{c_1^2}-1.$$ Expanding, we get

$$\frac{y^2}{c_1^2}-2\frac{y}{c_1^2}e^{\frac{x+c_2}{c_1}}+\frac{e^{2\frac{x+c_2}{c_1}}}{c_1^2}=\frac{y^2}{c_1^2}-1.$$
Notice that $y^2/c_1^2$ cancels. You get
$$-2\frac{y}{c_1^2}e^{\frac{x+c_2}{c_1}}+\frac{e^{2\frac{x+c_2}{c_1}}}{c_1^2}=-1.$$ Now just solve for $y$ in the obvious way:
$$2\frac{y}{c_1^2}e^{\frac{x+c_2}{c_1}}=1+\frac{e^{2\frac{x+c_2}{c_1}}}{c_1^2},$$
$$y=\frac{c_1^2}{2}e^{-\frac{x+c_2}{c_1}}+\frac{1}{2}e^{\frac{x+c_2}{c_1}}.$$

Comment: By $y$ I meant I was looking for $f(x$), i.e. $y=....$

Comment: Is my answer insufficient for finding $y=\cdots$?

Comment: I believe so, quadratics shouldn't enter the picture. I'd appreciate if you point out where my question is vague since there seems to be a disconnect here

Comment: Apologies. I worked through the details, and the quadratic is degenerate, so there is only one solution. I believe this is the cause of the confusion.

Comment: The solution manual gives $y = c_1 * cosh({x-c_2\over c_1}$, is there a trig relationship I'm failing to see here? Thanks again btw, for going so far with the calcs.

Comment: I did some digging on trig identities and found that if $c_1$ is in the numerator for both fractions before e then I can convert that to $c_1 cosh(etc)$, is there any apparent error I made to get here?

Comment: You would get that if the first square root in your question were replaced with $\sqrt{\frac{y^2-1}{c_1^2}}.$ Is there possibly a mistake in your earlier work?